# Delete Every even(uneven) row from a dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, delete-row

What is the most elegant way to delete every even/uneven row from a data-frame in R? My first try was to enter the numbers of every second row "by hand" (See below)

```
(SmallerDataFrame <- OriginalDataFrame[-c(2,4,6,8,10,12),])
```

Comment: DF[c(TRUE,FALSE),] ?

Comment: @Frank Recycling FTW!

Comment: might be easier to approach as - delete every even (or odd) row, then go from there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this

```
dat <- mtcars$cyl
toDelete <- seq(0, length(dat), 2)

toDelete

dat <-  dat[-toDelete, ]
```

For data frame,

```
dat <- mtcars
toDelete <- seq(1, nrow(dat), 2)
dat[ toDelete ,]
```